# STM32 data transfer via UART

Tags: uart, serial-communication, stm32f4discovery, stm32cubeide, nucleo

I have one stm32f407G-DISC1 and one NUCLEO-F420ZI development board. I want to collect data from the f407's internal accelerometer and transfer them to the NUCLEO board via UART. I collect and send data, but I cannot receive these data from NUCLEO. I'm sure the pins are connected correctly. I share the codes of both cards with you. Where do you think the problem might be?

Sender Code:

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * Copyright (c) 2024 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.
  *
  * This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
  * in the root directory of this software component.
  * If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "cmsis_os.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#include "MY_LIS3DSH.h"
#include "stdio.h"

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */
LIS3DSH_InitTypeDef myAccConfigDef;
/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
#define ACC_BUFFER_SIZE 400
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi1;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;

/* Definitions for ReadACCData */
osThreadId_t ReadACCDataHandle;
const osThreadAttr_t ReadACCData_attributes = {
  .name = "ReadACCData",
  .stack_size = 1024 * 4,
  .priority = (osPriority_t) osPriorityHigh,
};
/* Definitions for TransmitterTask */
osThreadId_t TransmitterTaskHandle;
const osThreadAttr_t TransmitterTask_attributes = {
  .name = "TransmitterTask",
  .stack_size = 1024 * 4,
  .priority = (osPriority_t) osPriorityLow,
};
/* Definitions for ACCDataQueue */
osMessageQueueId_t ACCDataQueueHandle;
const osMessageQueueAttr_t ACCDataQueue_attributes = {
  .name = "ACCDataQueue"
};
/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
int AccDataBufferIndex = 0;
LIS3DSH_DataRaw myData;
uint8_t drdyFlag = 0;
int16_t AccDataBuffer_16bit[1200];
uint8_t AccDataBuffer_8bit[ACC_BUFFER_SIZE * 3 * 2]; // 3 axes * 2 bytes];
/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void);
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void);
void ReadACCDataFunction(void *argument);
void TransmitterTaskFunction(void *argument);

/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
void LedBlink(LIS3DSH_DataRaw data);
/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_SPI1_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Init scheduler */
  osKernelInitialize();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_MUTEX */
  /* add mutexes, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_MUTEX */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_SEMAPHORES */
  /* add semaphores, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_SEMAPHORES */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_TIMERS */
  /* start timers, add new ones, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_TIMERS */

  /* Create the queue(s) */
  /* creation of ACCDataQueue */
  ACCDataQueueHandle = osMessageQueueNew (150, sizeof(uint16_t), &ACCDataQueue_attributes);

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_QUEUES */
  /* add queues, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_QUEUES */

  /* Create the thread(s) */
  /* creation of ReadACCData */
  ReadACCDataHandle = osThreadNew(ReadACCDataFunction, NULL, &ReadACCData_attributes);

  /* creation of TransmitterTask */
  TransmitterTaskHandle = osThreadNew(TransmitterTaskFunction, NULL, &TransmitterTask_attributes);

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_THREADS */
  /* add threads, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_THREADS */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_EVENTS */
  /* add events, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_EVENTS */

  /* Start scheduler */
  osKernelStart();

  /* We should never get here as control is now taken by the scheduler */
  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 8;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 336;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 7;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV4;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_5) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief SPI1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI1_Init 1 */
  /* SPI1 parameter configuration*/
  hspi1.Instance = SPI1;
  hspi1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi1.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_2;
  hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 10;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief USART1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 1 */
  huart1.Instance = USART1;
  huart1.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 2 */
  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
/* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_1 */
/* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_1 */

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOE_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(ACC_CS_GPIO_Port, ACC_CS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_12|GPIO_PIN_13|GPIO_PIN_14|GPIO_PIN_15, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : ACC_CS_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = ACC_CS_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(ACC_CS_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PA0 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PD12 PD13 PD14 PD15 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_12|GPIO_PIN_13|GPIO_PIN_14|GPIO_PIN_15;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : ACC_EXTI_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = ACC_EXTI_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(ACC_EXTI_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /* EXTI interrupt init*/
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI0_IRQn, 5, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI0_IRQn);

/* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
/* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */
void LedBlink(LIS3DSH_DataRaw data)
{
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_12 | GPIO_PIN_13 | GPIO_PIN_14 | GPIO_PIN_15, GPIO_PIN_RESET); // Reset all pins

    if (data.z > 5000)
    {
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_12 | GPIO_PIN_13 | GPIO_PIN_14 | GPIO_PIN_15, GPIO_PIN_SET); // Set all pins
    }
    if (data.x > 5000)
    {
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_14, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    }
    if (data.x < -5000)
    {
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_12, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    }
    if (data.y > 5000)
    {
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_13, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    }
    if (data.y < -5000)
    {
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_15, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    }
}


void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
{
  /* Prevent unused argument(s) compilation warning */
  UNUSED(GPIO_Pin);
  /* NOTE: This function Should not be modified, when the callback is needed,
           the HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback could be implemented in the user file
   */

    drdyFlag = 1;
    //HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_13);
}

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/* USER CODE BEGIN Header_ReadACCDataFunction */
/**
  * @brief  Function implementing the ReadACCData thread.
  * @param  argument: Not used
  * @retval None
  */
/* USER CODE END Header_ReadACCDataFunction */
void ReadACCDataFunction(void *argument)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 5 */
    HAL_StatusTypeDef uartStatus;
    myAccConfigDef.dataRate = LIS3DSH_DATARATE_400;
    myAccConfigDef.fullScale = LIS3DSH_FULLSCALE_2;
    myAccConfigDef.antiAliasingBW = LIS3DSH_FILTER_BW_50;
    myAccConfigDef.enableAxes = LIS3DSH_XYZ_ENABLE;
    myAccConfigDef.interruptEnable = true;
    int16_t dataIndex16Bit = 0;
    int16_t dataIndex8Bit = 0;
    LIS3DSH_Init(&hspi1, &myAccConfigDef);

    LIS3DSH_X_calibrate(-1000.0, 980.0);
    LIS3DSH_Y_calibrate(-1020.0, 1040.0);
    LIS3DSH_Z_calibrate(-920.0, 1040.0);
  /* Infinite loop */
  for(;;)
  {
      if (drdyFlag == 1)
      {
          drdyFlag = 0;
          myData = LIS3DSH_GetDataRaw();
          AccDataBuffer_8bit[dataIndex8Bit++] = myData.x & 0xFF;
          AccDataBuffer_8bit[dataIndex8Bit++] = (myData.x >> 8) & 0xFF;
          AccDataBuffer_16bit[dataIndex16Bit++] = myData.x;

          AccDataBuffer_8bit[dataIndex8Bit++] = myData.y & 0xFF;
          AccDataBuffer_8bit[dataIndex8Bit++] = (myData.y >> 8) & 0xFF;
          AccDataBuffer_16bit[dataIndex16Bit++] = myData.y;

          AccDataBuffer_8bit[dataIndex8Bit++] = myData.z & 0xFF;
          AccDataBuffer_8bit[dataIndex8Bit++] = (myData.z >> 8) & 0xFF;
          AccDataBuffer_16bit[dataIndex16Bit++] = myData.z;

          if (dataIndex16Bit == ACC_BUFFER_SIZE * 3)
          {
                dataIndex16Bit=0;
                dataIndex8Bit=0;
                uartStatus = HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, AccDataBuffer_8bit, ACC_BUFFER_SIZE * 6, HAL_MAX_DELAY);

          }
            LedBlink(myData);
      }
  }
    osDelay(1);
}
  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE END 5 */


/* USER CODE BEGIN Header_TransmitterTaskFunction */
/**
* @brief Function implementing the TransmitterTask thread.
* @param argument: Not used
* @retval None
*/
/* USER CODE END Header_TransmitterTaskFunction */
void TransmitterTaskFunction(void *argument)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TransmitterTaskFunction */
  /* Infinite loop */
  for(;;)
  {
    osDelay(1);
  }
  /* USER CODE END TransmitterTaskFunction */
}

/**
  * @brief  Period elapsed callback in non blocking mode
  * @note   This function is called  when TIM1 interrupt took place, inside
  * HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(). It makes a direct call to HAL_IncTick() to increment
  * a global variable "uwTick" used as application time base.
  * @param  htim : TIM handle
  * @retval None
  */
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Callback 0 */

  /* USER CODE END Callback 0 */
  if (htim->Instance == TIM1) {
    HAL_IncTick();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Callback 1 */

  /* USER CODE END Callback 1 */
}

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Receiver Code:

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * Copyright (c) 2024 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.
  *
  * This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
  * in the root directory of this software component.
  * If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "cmsis_os.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
#define RX_BUFFER_SIZE 2400 /* Assuming the same buffer size as the sender */
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;

/* Definitions for UARTRxTask */
osThreadId_t UARTRxTaskHandle;
const osThreadAttr_t UARTRxTask_attributes = {
  .name = "UARTRxTask",
  .stack_size = 2048 * 4,
  .priority = (osPriority_t) osPriorityHigh,
};
/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
uint8_t RxBuffer[RX_BUFFER_SIZE];
uint16_t RxIndex = 0;
int16_t AccData[RX_BUFFER_SIZE / 2]; // Buffer to store 16-bit accelerometer data
/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void);
void UARTRxTaskFunction(void *argument);

/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Init scheduler */
  osKernelInitialize();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_MUTEX */
  /* add mutexes, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_MUTEX */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_SEMAPHORES */
  /* add semaphores, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_SEMAPHORES */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_TIMERS */
  /* start timers, add new ones, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_TIMERS */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_QUEUES */
  /* add queues, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_QUEUES */

  /* Create the thread(s) */
  /* creation of UARTRxTask */
  UARTRxTaskHandle = osThreadNew(UARTRxTaskFunction, NULL, &UARTRxTask_attributes);

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_THREADS */
  /* add threads, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_THREADS */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTOS_EVENTS */
  /* add events, ... */
  /* USER CODE END RTOS_EVENTS */

  /* Start scheduler */
  osKernelStart();

  /* We should never get here as control is now taken by the scheduler */
  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {


    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 8;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 336;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 4;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV4;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_5) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief USART1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 1 */
  huart1.Instance = USART1;
  huart1.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
/* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_1 */
/* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_1 */

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_14, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PB0 PB14 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_14;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

/* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
/* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/* USER CODE BEGIN Header_UARTRxTaskFunction */
/**
  * @brief  Function implementing the UARTRxTask thread.
  * @param  argument: Not used
  * @retval None
  */
/* USER CODE END Header_UARTRxTaskFunction */
void UARTRxTaskFunction(void *argument)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 5 */
    HAL_StatusTypeDef uartStatus;


    /* Infinite loop */
    for (;;)
    {
        uartStatus = HAL_UART_Receive(&huart1, RxBuffer, RX_BUFFER_SIZE, 5000); // Receive 2400 bytes

        if (uartStatus == HAL_OK)
        {
            // Convert received 8-bit data to 16-bit data and store in AccData buffer
            for (uint16_t i = 0; i < RX_BUFFER_SIZE; i += 2)
            {
                AccData[RxIndex++] = (uint16_t)(RxBuffer[i] | (RxBuffer[i + 1] << 8));
            }

            RxIndex = 0; // Reset the index for the next reception
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Error receiving data via UART\n");
        }

        osDelay(1);
    }
  /* USER CODE END 5 */
}

/**
  * @brief  Period elapsed callback in non blocking mode
  * @note   This function is called  when TIM1 interrupt took place, inside
  * HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(). It makes a direct call to HAL_IncTick() to increment
  * a global variable "uwTick" used as application time base.
  * @param  htim : TIM handle
  * @retval None
  */
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Callback 0 */

  /* USER CODE END Callback 0 */
  if (htim->Instance == TIM1) {
    HAL_IncTick();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Callback 1 */

  /* USER CODE END Callback 1 */
}

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

It's actually a very simple application. I transferred a string between two cards, but it was only about 20 bytes. I get status OK feedback on the sender device, but it gives a timeout error on the receiver device. Even if I set the timeout period to maximum, it remains in that function for a long time, so it does not work properly.

Comment: Check that grounds are connected. Observe waveform on the UART line using oscilloscope or logic analyzer. Conduct loopback tests. Replace one of the endpoints with "known good" UART receiver/transmitter such as an USB-UART converter connected to PC.

Answer (score 0):

1. First analyze the hardware problem. Use an oscilloscope or USB TO TTL tool to capture TX and RX data to confirm whether the hardware is normal.
2. Check whether the software baud rate and parity bit are configured properly.
3. If everything is checked, you can contact me and we will analyze your code together.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest first x'mitt/receieve a single character, and then after get align with the  actual data. Try instead of using blocking method use, non blocking method(interrupt).